# Jquery Undo - preventdefault

Tags: jquery

I have a some textboxes and a drop down. 
If the user does not have permission to modify them, I like to 
show a message and undo what they selected in teh case of a drop down 
or to undo what they types - in the case of a text box.

I tried the following for a drop down but did not work:

```
    $('#ReasonDropDown').change(function () {

        if (permission == "False") {
            alert("You do not have permssion to make to modify this field.");
            event.preventDefault(); 
            return false;
        }
    });
```

It simply did not undo what I had selected.

Comment: You'll have to write code to remove text and uncheck. preventDefault() and return false only stop event bubbling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below and it will works for any number of `select` element.

```
$('select').attr('data-default', function() {
    return this.value;
}).change(function(e) {
    if (permission == 'False') {
        alert('You do not have permission to modify this field.');
        this.value = $(this).data('default');
    }
});
```

And also can do similar for `text` fields.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/628/)**